# Remove extension from URL (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to remove the extension from a URL.

I implemented a code in the `.htaccess` file and then removed all the extensions from site pages. This way, I could achieve my goal to some extent; while staying on site, if I click any URL, it takes me to the relevant page without displaying the extension.

*But*, if I access the URL manually by typing the extension in the URL, it  displays the page again, but I don't want that.

For example, if I manually type `website.com/page.html` in the URL, it should redirect me automatically to `website.com/page`.

What should I write in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Can you post the rewrite rule that you have written so far?

Comment: I've cleaned up the grammar and formatting of the question a bit. You can further improve it by adding your current rule, as asked for in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This is what i am provided.

```
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is working totally fine.